# How to disable notification sound in Facebook application

Tags: notifications, facebook, oneplus-two

I have the Facebook application installed and I can't seem to figure out how to turn off the (really loud and sharp) notifications sound, what I tried so far was

1. go to `Settings > App Settings > Sounds in the App` and untick the option
2. go to `Settings > Notifications Settings` but I couldn't find a relevant setting

I don't want to mute or lower the device volume because I have other apps with  notifications that are actually important for me, I use a OnePlus2 with Oxygen3.6.1 if it helps

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case. Edit the app with Apk Editor from [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor.pro). Delete the .ogg files compile it and install. If not so, check whether your phone has notification sound scheme at settings and notifications since you want other apps notifying.

Comment: That's a valid (and pretty clever) solution, but won't that mean I would have to redo the same process every time a new version will be available ? Also, for some reason, `Settings > Notifications` on the device doesn't handle sounds, which you would think it would :/

Comment: Yeah but recompilation takes only minutes. But earlier I answered some question about how to disable an app from being updated from store. Use that application that edits to change package name of the app. You won't receive updates

Answer (score 0):

According to the article [How do I turn off in-app sounds?](https://m.facebook.com/help/android-app/1546034095653735), you should be able to disable the sounds under the **Media and Contacts** entry at the bottom the of the Setting section. However on my Wife's Samsung Galaxy S9 (SM-G960U1) that section was missing:

[image: IMG:]

Instead, I was able to open that section using **Find Friends -> Contacts -> Settings**. No idea why the section was missing from the main settings page, but any changes you make still seem to work once you can get into that section.